# What's wrong with my simple HTTP socket based proxy script?

Tags: python, sockets, http-proxy

I wrote a simple Python script for a proxy functionality. It works fine, however, if the requested webpage has many other HTTP requests, e.g. Google maps, the page is rendered quite slow.

Any hints as to what might be the bottleneck in my code, and how I can improve?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket,select,re
from threading import Thread

class ProxyServer():
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host=host
        self.port=port 
        self.sk1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def startServer(self):
        self.sk1.bind((self.host,self.port))
        self.sk1.listen(256)
        print "proxy is ready for connections..."
        while(1):
            conn,clientAddr = self.sk1.accept()
           # print "new request coming in from " + str(clientAddr)
            handler = RequestHandler(conn)
            handler.start()


class RequestHandler(Thread):

    def __init__(self, sk1):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.clientSK = sk1
        self.buffer = ''
        self.header = {}





    def run(self):
        sk1 = self.clientSK 
        sk2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        while 1:
            self.buffer += sk1.recv(8192)
            if self.buffer.find('\n') != -1:
                break;

        self.header = self.processHeader(self.buffer)
        if len(self.header)>0: #header got processed
            hostString = self.header['Host']
            host=port=''
            if hostString.__contains__(':'): # with port number
                host,port = hostString.split(':')
            else:
                host,port = hostString,"80"
            sk2.connect((host,int(port)))

        else:
            sk1.send('bad request')
            sk1.close();
            return
        inputs=[sk1,sk2]
        sk2.send(self.buffer)
        #counter
        count = 0
        while 1:
            count+=1
            rl, wl, xl = select.select(inputs, [], [], 3)
            if xl:
                break
            if rl:
                for x in rl:
                    data = x.recv(8192)
                    if x is sk1:
                        output = sk2
                    else:
                        output = sk1
                    if data:
                        output.send(data)
                        count = 0
            if count == 20:
                 break


        sk1.close()
        sk2.close()



    def processHeader(self,header):
        header = header.replace("\r\n","\n")
        lines = header.split('\n')    
        result = {}
        uLine = lines[0] # url line
        if len(uLine) == 0: return result # if url line empty return empty dict
        vl = uLine.split(' ')
        result['method'] = vl[0]
        result['url'] = vl[1]
        result['protocol'] = vl[2]
        for line in lines[1: - 1]:
            if len(line)>3: # if line is not empty
                exp = re.compile(': ')
                nvp = exp.split(line, 1)
                if(len(nvp)>1):
                    result[nvp[0]] = nvp[1]
        return result




if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "0.0.0.0", 8088
    proxy = ProxyServer(HOST,PORT)
    proxy.startServer()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your speed problems are, but here are some other nits I found to pick:

```
result['protocal'] = vl[2]
```

should be

```
result['protocol'] = vl[2]
```

This code is indented one level too deep:

```
sk2.connect((host,int(port)))
```

You can use [this](http://mg.pov.lt/blog/profiling.html) decorator to profile your individual methods by line.